# Можно ли с помощью jQuery вставить кусок PHP кода в нужное место?

Tags: jquery, php

Есть div с классом container и мне нужно в конце добавить PHP код. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Вы пишите абсурдные вещи!
2. Я думаю что нет.

Answer (score 2):

Добавить именно PHP-код невозможно.

Понимаете, PHP - это серверный язык, то есть клиенту в браузер приходит только "готовая" страница. javaScript - клиентский язык, то есть вся работа ведется **только** со страницей, которая есть в браузере.

В вашем случае лучший вариант - это Ajax. То есть с помощью языка javaScript вы обращаетесь к какому-либо скрипту PHP на сервере и получаете готовый ответ и уже данный "ответ" можете вставить в конец страницы.

Answer (score -2):

Можно так

```
<?$KtoZdes = "Здесь Скоро Будет Город-Сад";?>
<script>
    jQuery("#...").html("<?=$KtoZdes?>");
</script>;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.